# How to find Agend Pools settings in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to set up Azure DevOps with one of my projects for the first time.  Starting out, I've created a demo project for learning purposes.

I've been able to set up a build pipeline, but I want to set up an agent pool with local agent pools.

In Microsoft's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser), it says to click "Organization Settings" under Azure Devops and then I should see "Agent Pools" under "Pipelines".

The view in my browser (attached) looks completely different from what is in the documentation and I can't find these settings in spite of hours of searching.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I find the tab to do what I want?[image]

Comment: Hi @Vivian. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answers could give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find "Organization Settings" here:
[image]

Then you can see the Agent Pools page consistent with the document in a series of settings:

[image]